# como hacer uso CASE WHEN___THEN___ cuando quiero crear una variable categórica "1" del lo contrario "0" en SQL. En el siguiente caso:

Tags: mysql, sql

En SQL quiero hacer lo siguiente Cuento con una tabla donde dos calumnas son una numérica (gasto)y otra categórica con tres niveles (alto,medio bajo), lo que quiero es crear una nueva variable categórica ("1" y "0") a partir de las otras dos, de la siguiente manera:
En categoria el nivel alto sí el gasto es mayor a 10 ponga "1" de lo contrario "0",
En categoria el nivel medio si el gasto es mayor a 20 ponga "1" de lo contrario "0",
En categoria el nivel bajo si el gasto es mayor a 8 ponga "1" de lo contrario "0".

Creo que con CASE  lo puedo hacer pero cuando quiero que tenga en cuenta la categoría no logro hacerlo bien.
Alguna sugerencia, muchas gracias

Comment: Deberias incluir el codigo de lo que has intentado.

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** y **[¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Hola intenta [aquí](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) hay mucho ejemplos sobre como usar el case en SQL-SERVER

En lo particular pienso que este te podría funcionar:

```
SELECT   ProductNumber, Name, "Price Range" =   
      CASE   
         WHEN ListPrice =  0 THEN 'Mfg item - not for resale'  
         WHEN ListPrice < 50 THEN 'Under $50'  
         WHEN ListPrice >= 50 and ListPrice < 250 THEN 'Under $250'  
         WHEN ListPrice >= 250 and ListPrice < 1000 THEN 'Under $1000'  
         ELSE 'Over $1000'  
      END  
FROM Production.Product  
ORDER BY ProductNumber ;
```

Saludos!